# Check if the char is *English* Alphabetic or not

Tags: python, methods

I want to check if the char in string is English alphabetic or not. I mean, the method `is.alpha()` will return `True` if I put Hebrew letter, but I want only English letter.

Comment: Please read [ask] and add what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3):

Check if it is letter and if it is ascii character

```
def isEnglish(s):
    return s.isascii() and s.isalpha()
```

Comment: Just note that `isascii` is a python3 function

Comment: A potential problem is that many ASCII characters are also French and Spanish letters (as well as being in many other languages).

Comment: You are wrong this will not let those characters pass `isEnglish('á') ` returns **False** so does `isEnglish('š') `

Comment: You're missing my point — which as that a character like `a` is used in both languages, so what you've proposed is not checking for characters that are strictly English.

Comment: But all characters from english are used in different languages!?!?

Comment: Precisely. I think the OP means Roman characters, not English ones. Characters typically aren't language-specific.

Comment: No op wants to detect if there are any characters foreign to english language, so my answer still stands. I gues we will know for sure when OP confirms